# How do I manage CalDAV-provided tasks?

Tags: sync, to-do-list, caldav

On my phone, I have a calendar synchronized via CalDAV-Sync on a server of mine. On the desktop, I edit them with Thunderbird, and since Thunderbird can associate tasks to a calendar, I was wondering, if is there a way to see those tasks on Android too, since I can already see (and edit) the calendar itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CalDAV-Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib) provides another app, [OpenTasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.tasks) to support task. From its description,

> To get task support, please install this task app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.tasks

The following YouTube video is a demo of the task app in progress: [Preview of task sync in CalDAV-Sync for Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3IJC6IcbiQ)